# Counterexample to: An algebra isomorphism between symmetric Frobenius algebras preserves the Frobenius structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A, B$ be finite-dimensional symmetric Frobenius algebras over a field $k$.
I use the characterization that there is a linear map $\alpha : A \to k$ (or $\beta$ for $B$) such that precomposing with the respective multiplication yields a non-degenerate symmetric pairing.

- Given an algebra isomorphism $f:A\to B$, is it necessarily the case that $\beta \circ f = \alpha$?

I don't think so, it would in particular mean that any two symmetric Frobenius structures on a vector space are the same.
Does anyone have a counterexample?

I know that one would be given by a [unimodular pivotal Hopf algebras that is not unibalanced](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.00321), but I can't come up with one of those (all unimodular pivotal HAs I know are unibalanced).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $H$ be a factorizable Hopf algebra with nontrivial ribbon structure. These exist.
Then by results of the paper linked in the OP, there is a nondegenerate symmetric form $\lambda$ on $H$.
Also, $H$ has an invertible central element: The ribbon $v\in Z(H)$, which is not equal to $1$.
Define $\lambda_v(h) = \lambda(vh)$, then $\lambda_v$ provides another nondegenerate symmetric form on $H$ which is not equal to $\lambda$, since $v \neq 1$.

Therefore the algebra isomorphism $\operatorname{id}_A$ does not provide an isomorphism of Frobenius algebras.